# ROS installation failed

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi !

I am trying to install ROS on a laptop in order to get it working with the Turtlebot2. I tried to install kobuki's packages thanks to this tutorial : http://www.ros.org/wiki/kobuki/Tutorials/Installation ; but something seems to have failed.
First, I couldn't do this step :

```
roscd kobuki_ftdi 
make udev
```

The computer answered :

```
make: *** No rule to make target `udev'.  Stop.
```

And I might say that I am not really sure about what this step of the installation is for.

Then, if I tried to launch any launch file or script,

```
roslaunch kobuki_node minimal.launch
```

the computer answered that the package doesn't exist :

```
[kobuki_node] is not a package or launch file name
```

Although I did follow all the previous step with success (except the udev one).

As you suggested, I also tried http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot/Tutorials/groovy/Installation
I ran :

```
. /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash
rosrun kobuki_ftdi create_udev_rules
```

and got this answer :

```
This script copies a udev rule to /etc to facilitate bringing
up the kobuki usb connection as /dev/kobuki.

[sudo] password for turtlebot: 

Restarting udev

udev stop/waiting
udev start/running, process 4208
```

But whenever I try to roslaunch a kobuki_package I still got the same error as above (and I need the auto_docking package). If I try to run a turtlebot's package,

```
roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch
```

I got this error :

```
WARNING: unable to configure logging. No log files will be generated
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
WARNING: disk usage in log directory [/home/turtlebot/.ros/log] is over 1GB.
It's recommended that you use the 'rosclean' command.

Cannot locate [roslaunch]Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [rosversion]: command [rosversion roslaunch] returned with code [1]. 

Param xml is <param command="rosversion roslaunch" name="rosversion"/>
```

I don't know what went wrong and any hint about how to fix the situation is welcome.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66797/ros-installation-failed/) by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2013-07-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) on 2013-07-08**:
If you're following a tutorial, can you include a link to the one you're using? Also - copy&pasted error messages would be helpful.

**Comment by [airizarry8](https://answers.ros.org/users/5153/airizarry8/) on 2013-07-08**:
I have the same problem, then when i try to roslaunch kobuki_node minimal.launch, my dashboard said Kobuki: Device does not exist. Waiting...

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-07-08**:
It might be a different problem than mine. It seems like your packages are correctly installed. Are you sure your bot is plugged to the computer and powered ?

**Comment by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) on 2013-07-09**:
What happens when you start a roscore, talker, and listener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I finally solved my problem. Here is what worked for me :

1. I uninstalled everything linked to ROS (with purge option), deleted opt and etc ros folders
2. I followed this tutorial : http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Ubuntu until **1.5 Initialize rosdep** step.
3. To install rosdep, I used this command line :

   sudo pip install -U rosdep

That I found in this tutorial : http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosdep and checked that rosdep version was ok with this command line :

```
rosdep --version
```

(it has to be at least 0.10.19 version)

4. And then I followed **1.5 Initialize rosdep** and following steps from the first quoted tutorial

And everything was working fine after that.

---

Originally posted by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) with karma: 318 on 2013-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-07-10**:
Why exactly do you used the pip version of rosdep and not the debian package `python-rosdep`? Or, does it make a difference? The debian version says it's 0.10.21

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-07-10**:
Well, it didn't work for me when I tried python-rosdep. I always ended up with 0.9.3 version when I used it. Even after I updated. I don't know why. There were three different instructions I could try, I tried them and this one was the only one which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you try running these two lines from the tutorial yet?

```
. /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash
rosrun kobuki_ftdi create_udev_rules
```

When I installed my TurtleBot 2 I used the Turtlebot-specific line of tutorials (http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot/Tutorials) rather than the Kobuki tutorials. Not sure which you've used, but the Turtlebot ones have worked for me.

Specific Tutorial:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot/Tutorials/groovy/Installation

---

Originally posted by [BlitherPants](https://answers.ros.org/users/4967/blitherpants/) with karma: 504 on 2013-07-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [airizarry8](https://answers.ros.org/users/5153/airizarry8/) on 2013-07-08**:
yes i did, i used the same page

**Comment by [BlitherPants](https://answers.ros.org/users/4967/blitherpants/) on 2013-07-08**:
On the Turtlebot tutorials, the bringup command is 'roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch'. I don't remember ever needing to run 'kobuki_node minimal.launch'.

**Comment by [airizarry8](https://answers.ros.org/users/5153/airizarry8/) on 2013-07-08**:
your absolutely right, is not in the turtlebot tutorials, but you can follow the kobuki tutorials, kobuki is the base platform of the turtlebot 2, by the way BlitherPants i think it was magic but now my turtlebot work, after the 101 time i evaluate that command

**Comment by [BlitherPants](https://answers.ros.org/users/4967/blitherpants/) on 2013-07-08**:
Of course, but I'm a little confused. I thought you said you followed the same page? The page I posted is part of Turtlebot tutorials, not Kobuki tutorials. I have no idea if mixing directions from different tutorials will work. Just saying, following the Turtlebot tutorial solely does work.

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-07-08**:
Well I didn't follow that page, but the kobuki tutorial. But they linked a page with the command lines that you posted, and so I tried them. It didn't make anything work. I'll try to install Turtlebot's packages and will let you know.

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-07-08**:
I just updated the question after I tried to install Turtlebot's packages.

**Comment by [BlitherPants](https://answers.ros.org/users/4967/blitherpants/) on 2013-07-09**:
Weird; I never saw the error about logging or disk usage.
I'm grasping at straws a little, but did you also run these lines (before the udev stuff) after installing ROS?
'sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-turtlebot ros-groovy-turtlebot-apps ros-groovy-turtlebot-viz '

**Comment by [BlitherPants](https://answers.ros.org/users/4967/blitherpants/) on 2013-07-09**:
I'm a newbie at this stuff myself, but I'm also curious why you're getting the disk error. Are you really low on space or something?

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-07-09**:
Yes, I installed turtlebot packages as well, like you suggested. I do not think that the disk lacks of space. I don't know why I get this error. I am currently trying to uninstall and reinstall ROS and kobuki packages from scratch